# Write array with opcua

Tags: python, opc-ua, opc

everyone!

I need to write a variable as an array (list) to the OPC server. I am using Python and Python OPC-UA.
In the picture you can see the name and structure of the variable where I am trying to write the data.

[opc-image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gHmC0.png)

I try to use this code and get an error

```
    q = [0]*50
    data = client.get_node(f'ns=3;s="OSC_Profile"."THIS"')
    dv = ua.Variant(q, ua.VariantType.ExtensionObject)
    data.set_value(dv)
```

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [18], in <cell line: 9>()
     20     dv = ua.Variant(q, ua.VariantType.ExtensionObject)
---> 21     data.set_value(dv)

KeyError: 'int'
```

I would be glad if someone could suggest the right way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok you have a custom datatype so you have to create the corresponding class:

```
q = [ua.OSC(...), ua.OSC(...), ...]
data.set_value(ua.Variant(q, ua.VariantType.ExtensionObject))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Could you tell me how I can create a corresponding class?

Comment: Call client.load_type_definitions() after connect and then do this: osc = get_ua_class(OSC)()
        osc .ID = 3
        osc .Gender = True
        osc .Comments = 'Test string'

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Schroeder. My final code looks like:

```
from opcua import Client 
from opcua import ua
from opcua.common.type_dictionary_buider import get_ua_class

try:
    client.connect()
    client.load_type_definitions()

    data = client.get_node(f'adress')

    osc = get_ua_class('OSC')()
    osc.Id= 50.
    osc.Age= 60.
    osc.Weight= 70.

    q = [osc]*50

    dv = ua.Variant(q, ua.VariantType.ExtensionObject)
    data.set_attribute(13, ua.DataValue(dv)) #13 - id of attribute

finally:
    client.disconnect()
```